# Can I use an induction cooker to restore silica gel's water absorbency?

Tags: oven, cookware, induction

It was mentioned in an [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/12728/22) to my [previous question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/12723/22) that silica gel can be heated in the oven to restore its water absorbent properties.  I only have access to an induction cooker, so it possible to use that instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you heat silica gel, you will drive out the water from it. What actually happens depends on how you heat it, and how hot it gets.

If you have a thick layer, you may not be able to effectively dehydrate the crystals in a reasonable time.

If you try to use a gas oven, you're on a loser because burning gas makes water and carbon dioxide - it takes ages trying to do the job with moist heat.

You might be able to do a thin layer in the bottom of a pan on an induction cooker, but remember that you cannot achieve temperature control very easily. The optimum range to regenerate the silica gel is 120 degC to 140 degC, and you really want a gradual temperature rise to do the job effectively - better to hold the stuff at 80 to 90 deg C for half an hour before you go to 120 deg C.

If you try to dehydrate too quickly, the crystals will crack and break up, so you may end up with a fine powder, rather than crystals.

Comment: Are there better ways beside putting in a oven or on a induction cooker. (cause the comments made here make me scare that the silica gel powder can kill or injure people badly) Can I put it under the sun and wait for it to change from pink to blue colour? (I would appreciate if someone can suggest a method that is simple & safe. Thanks)

Answer (score -1):

Wow that's a tricky one!  If I had to, not saying that you should (had to CYA) I would use a cast iron pot.  Cast iron is the only material that I know, that can heat empty without any ill effects.  I would make a rack from crumpled foil (aluminum) since it doesn’t conduct the heat from the induction cooker and will prevent contact with the bottom.  Also keep the lid slightly cracked for venting and to prevent the heat from building to high.  There are different melting points to various plastics, so I would keep the temperate under 200 degrees since plastic food wrap melts at approx. 220 deg.  An oven thermometer would be a wise investment.  This may take longer to dry out the Silica Gel but if an induction cooker is the only method available to me, this would be the safer choice.

Comment: If you look at the advice he received earlier you'll see that the target temperature for drying silica gel is 250 °F (around 120 °C, I think). Not sure what the highest temperature is can tolerate is.

Comment: Yes, but he did not specify whether the silica gel was in a little plastic container, pouch or loose.  I didn't want to take a chance.

Comment: stainless steel can also be heated empty to high temps. It may discolor slightly if you go really high, but not around 220°F.

Comment: To say "crumpled foil (aluminum) since it doesn’t conduct the heat from the induction cooker" is not the truth - you meant  that aluminium doesn't heat up from the induction coil. Aluminium conducts heat very efficiently - or you wouldn't be using it!

Comment: This answer seems entirely speculative, and in the context of a potentially dangerous substance, I don't think we want speculation.

Comment: Aluminum is a good conductor of regular heat, but the question was about Induction Electromagnetic Heat which alum cannot conduct. The transfer heat from cast iron to foil is not significant enough to be a concern.  My point was to avoid contact with the Cast Iron, due to the quick heating of electromagnet energy.  The foil would be a protective layer and SG properties can degrade if heated too high, absorb any oils on the bottom of the pot (seasoning) or just pick up the iron color making it more difficult to determine when the SG is dried out.  But I appreciate you telling me what I meant.

Comment: Lastly, It seems you speculated on my knowledge of the subject. It's no more dangerous than baking a cake in a cast iron pot that is on top of a burner.  Even baking cakes needs safety precautions. Sources, on the internet, craft stores or even companies who sell SG. Did you know the cheapest form of SG is Kitty Litter.  Works great to control humidity in closets, vitamin & prescription bottles, crispness in food, chips, cookies, Japanese wasabi chips, I use it for camping, you can put in your silver or jewelry cases to slow down tarnishing. I could go on, but I digress.

Comment: If you didn't mean what @klypos suggests, you are wrong. Aluminium can conduct heat from any source equally well, this is basic physics. But I still suspect that you two mean the same thing, only you are using the term "conducting" wrong, and klypos corrected your usage.

Comment: @Onepotmeals - you wrote a faux pas - forget it. Don't compound the error by talking about cat litter, which is NOT silica gel - it is usually some kind of absorbent material, and the important factor is that it absorbs odors. Y the info is useful, but it is off subject. I suspect you have the Paligorskite variety.

Comment: @Aaronaut - the health concerns for silica gel are mainly to do with the very fine small particle size forms that are produced industrially to help tablets disintegrate in the stomach. If you meet that stuff, it is usually mixed into something, and you get problems if you INHALE the powder and it gets in your lung during manufacturing processes. As a foodstuff it is mostly harmless, it is a problem for those working with it - not in the end product, not a problem for end users - an inert excipient.